# Transfering XTZ from tz address in Galleon to KT address

Tags: baking, kt1, galleon, babylon

I am trying to send some XTZ from a tz to a KT address on Galleon. It says I need to interact with Contracts. What then are the steps to send XTZs to that KT address?

I suppose generally, bakers will have issues sending to their delegators who still use Kt addresses if this is so complicated.

Any help of how to use the Galleon Wallet to send XTZ to Kt nowadays?

[image: GalleonKTtransfer]

[image: SmartContractInterface]

Edit: Added Screenshots
Edit2: TezBox actually works fine. Seems to be a Galleon issue

Answer (score 0):

If the KT1 uses the default manager.tz script, sending tokens to it should be totally transparent because this script has a default entrypoint of type unit.

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? It tells me to interact with contract and then I'm getting a UI which tells me to add some Micheline code and a bunch of other stuff.